# Android what may cause a reference to service being null

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have the following code being executed, I'm running this through a debugger and audioPlayerConnection.service is always null. Why may this be?

The various log calls don't always seem to be executed either (I guess this may have to do with the service being already starte).

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AudioPlayer.class);
    AudioPlayerConnection audioPlayerConnection = new AudioPlayerConnection();
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, audioPlayerConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

AudioPlayerConnection

```
    public class AudioPlayerConnection implements ServiceConnection {
        public IBinder service;

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            this.service = service;
            Log.d("hmm", "audio service connected!!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        }
    }
```

AudioPlayer

```
public class AudioPlayer extends Service {

    public ArrayList<MediaPlayer> audioResources = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();

    public AudioPlayer() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("hmm", "audio service binded!!!");
        return new AudioPlayerBinder();
    }

    public class AudioPlayerBinder extends Binder {
        public void stopAll()
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (MediaPlayer mp : audioResources)
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                audioResources.remove(i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        public void add(Integer resourceId, boolean loop)
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(null, resourceId);

            if (loop)
            {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                audioResources.add(mp);
            }

            mp.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you call audioPlayerConnection = new AudioPlayerConnection(); then audioPlayerConnection simply cannot be null

Comment: audioPlayerConnection.service is probably null because bindService() is asynchronous, and the value won't be set until onServiceConnected() is called, and you're probably checking before it's called. That being said, what you're doing doesn't make a whole lot of sense, you should review the documentation.

Comment: It's audioPlayerConnection.service that is null.

Comment: I'm trying to make a separate 'service' that handles all my intended audio interactions. Otherwise I have to keep references to them throughout my application when I would like to stop them (in the case of setting them to loop).

Comment: aaah,  ok sorry,  so you cannot bind to a Service? can you post a manifesto?

Comment: Yes, but holding a reference to the IBinder isn't going to accomplish much, AudioPlayerBinder should have a getService() method that retrieves the enclosing Service instance, and a reference to the Service instance is typically stored as a member variable in the Activity.

Comment: Please review the pattern @ http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: @svenoaks getService is not needed,  all he needs is to cast IBinder to AudioPlayerBinder

Comment: @pskink I suppose you're right, but he's declaring audioPlayerConnection in the local scope, so it can't be accessed later. This, and the fact that bindService() is asynchronous, and he's trying to do things with audioPlayerConnection in the local scope is the source of the problems here.

Comment: @pskink Anyway, the getService() pattern is cleaner, more maintainable and what is demonstrated by Google, so I'd recommend doing it that way regardless.

Comment: i dont know,  why to expose the whole Service while you can expose the interface with  methods used in activity - service communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring audioPlayerService in the local scope where you are calling bindService(). The call to bindService is asynchronous, and onServiceConnected() is not being called before you are (presumably) trying to use audioPlayerConnection as if the Service was already bound.

Comment: Thank you I think you've answered my question with it being the asynchronous behavior causing this. I'm not too sure what you mean by audioPlayerService (do you mean audioPlayerConnection.service?) being in the local scope though?

Comment: @Chris sorry I meant audioServiceConnection.